# Why visual studio 2017 opens a file called "mat.inl.hpp" when building my code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, mat

I am making a code in `c++` and `opencv 3.2` to capture live stream video and track hand motion.

Then I measure the angle between a specified point on a drawn line and the hand centroid wherever it is.

But when debugging a debug error appear like that :

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD99459D98 in ROM.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000E82DEFC640. occurred

and opens a file called `mat.inl.hpp`, the mouse cursor is pointing to the return line in the following code :

```
    inline
Mat& Mat::operator = (const MatExpr& e)
{
    e.op->assign(e, *this);
    return *this;
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue!

Yes i used that class in the code many times, and i think that the first line of code which is causing the issue :-

```
Mat image = Mat::zeros(400, 400, CV_8UC3);

line(image, CvPoint(200, 200), CvPoint(400, 200), Scalar(110, 220, 0), 2, 8);
line(image, CvPoint(200, 200), CvPoint(X, Y), Scalar(110, 220, 0), 2, 8);
            double angle = atan2(Y, X);
            double b = (angle * 180 / 3.14159265);
            double a = abs((angle * 180 / 3.14159265));
            cout << a;
```

Comment: Most likely some of the code you call includes that header. You should be able to see from the stacktrace how you got there.  Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: It makes sense for this header to be included because you are using `Mat` class.

Comment: I edited the question and added the lines that i think it cause the issue